# I start at square 1 and have to finish at square 7, moving at each step to a higher numbered adjacent square. How many possible routes are there?

Tags: combinatorics

How would I use combinations and permutations formulae for questions like this?

The original question is:

> I start at square 1 and have to finish at square 7, moving at each step to a higher numbered adjacent square.  How many possible routes are there?

Here is an image of this:

[image]

I solved this by drawing branches for each possibility and counting how many paths there were to square $7$. The answer I got was $13$.

Is there any quicker way to do this? Does there exist a general formula one could make questions with a much greater number of squares?

Comment: There are 8 paths to square 6, and 13 paths to square 7. If you were to add a square 8, how many paths go there? Remember that each path to square 8 will have to get there from square 6 or square 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be the number of paths from square $1$ to square $n$ if the only admissible moves are to move from a square to a higher-numbered adjacent square.

There is only one path to the first square: Remain there.  Hence, $P(1) = 1$.

There is only one path from square $1$ to square $2$: Move from square $1$ to square $2$.  Hence, $P(2) = 1$.

There are two paths from square $1$ to square $3$:  Move from square $1$ to square $2$ and then to square $3$ or move directly from square $1$ to square $3$.  Hence, $P(3) = 2$.

If $n \geq 3$, square $n$ can be reached by first taking a path to square $n - 1$, of which there are $P(n - 1)$, and then moving to square $n$ or by taking a path to square $n - 2$, of which there are $P(n - 2)$, and then moving directly to square $n$.  Hence, $P(n)$ satisfies the recurrence relation
$$P(n) = P(n - 1) + P(n - 2),~\text{if \(n \geq 3\)}$$

Thus,
\begin{align*}
P(1) & = 1\\
P(2) & = 1\\
P(n) & = P(n - 1) + P(n - 2),~\text{if \(n \geq 3\)}
\end{align*}
which is just the recursive definition of the Fibonacci numbers.  You can verify by direct calculation that $P(7) = 13$, as you found.